# How do I space quads evenly?

Tags: modeling, add-on, vertices, faces, topology

Is there a way in blender or an addon that allows me to select a bunch of faces (or verts) and evenly distributes (or relaxes) them into quads clean quads. 
Without screwing up the vert ID/order.

Edit:
I would like to have the shapes of my quads to turn into perfect squares while maintaining the volume of the object and the vertex order.

[image: uneven quads to even quads]

Comment: I would like to have the shapes of my quads to turn into perfect squares while maintaining the volume of the object and the vertex order.

Comment: look for the `edit` button at the bottom of your Question's content and press it to make changes to your original Question.

Comment: I think it's impossible to preserve volume of the object *and* make all the polygons as perfect squares. Something will be sacrificed. One tool would be smoothing, but as modifier (either Smooth or Laplacian). It allows setting a vertex group which will control where smooth takes place; so several modifiers probably might change things a bit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Select the inner *Vertices*, press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Smooth* and adjust [Smooth Vertex](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/deforming/smooth.html) settings:

[image]

You can also access *Smooth Vertex* operator settings via <kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image: Smooth]

Another way is selecting a whole row or column of vertex and then *Scale* in X or Y axis to a factor or Zero with <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Alternatively place the 3D cursor over the vertex you wish to align to, press <kbd>.</kbd> to transform relative to the *3D Cursor* position, and then repeate the scale process described above. <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

[image: Scale]

Comment: That works great on a 2d surface like a plane. But on anything else it will loose volume. Smooth is essentially just relaxing the geometry.

I would like to have the shapes of my quads to turn into perfect squares while maintaining the volume of the object and the vertex order.

Comment: @user3730158 you should include the extra limiting criteria in your Question, so that people can give more exact answers.

Comment: ... and so that they're not just wasting their time giving what turn out to be inexact ones.

Comment: You may also look into Laplacian Smooth which I believe has improved smoothing algorithms that better preserve volume while smoothing mesh.

Answer (score 14):

LoopTools are great for this. It's an Addon which can be enabled in the User Preferences, it ships with Blender. To use it, select an Edge Loop, expand the options of LoopTools in the Tools Panel, and try the Relax Tool, like indicated here:

[image: LoopTools Relax]

Using the **Selection** Mode the Relaxing will really only happen on selected vertices (can also be faces). Using **Parallel** it will operate on loops which are parallel to the selected one.