# Is there a simple way to straighten this line of vertices?

Tags: modeling, vertices

[image]

I'm somewhat new to Blender.
I have a simple mesh that I used proportional editing on.
Now I want to straighten out the outer four corner edges.
(ie the selected vertices when the .blend file opens)
I've seen some answers but can't get them to work.
Thanks for any ideas to try.

Here's the copied link to the .blend file:

[image]

Thanks for any ideas.

edit: okay, thanks, here's a picture...wondering how to straighten out that line of vertices, thanks again for any ideas

edit:
@Brian, Okay, so now my question is how to make it so, in this second image, these two selected vertices are on an axis? Then I can then select and scale the rest of the line of vertices and scale them to that axis. I don't know how to align these two vertices to any axis. Thanks.

(Well, forget that second image, not enough reputation to post two links, so the vertices I'm talking about are on the left side of the first image, the topmost
vertice, and the fourth up from the bottom.)

@Jesse Can you get the line of vertices I refer to to line up in a straight line between the two vertices I'm referring to with this technique? I couldn't do it.

Comment: Hello and welcome, you did it right, and your file is welcome, but you shouldn't rely on it exclusively for diagnose purposes. Please post some images of what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33525/straighten-vertices-along-a-line and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/how-do-i-space-quads-evenly/64595#64595

Comment: Okay, thanks, this one did work, but I was not able to  select the added

Comment: Okay, thanks, this one did work,
Chebhou, at
"Straighten edges not on axis"
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/straighten-edges-not-on-axis
but I was not able to  select the added
edge, because it was so mingled in with the selected vertices. So I separated, the edge, moved it exactly y-1, then did the scaling, deleted the edge, and moved the selected vertices back exactly y+1. So a bit tedious to straighten out a line of vertices. Wondering if there's a simpler way.

Comment: @frew - yes, there is, S, Y, 0 (zero).

Comment: Hi. If you need to comment on an answer, use the comment box below that answer instead of editing your comments into the question.

Comment: Okay. Couldn't add link to image in comment so went back up to main edit. Still trying to figure out easiest way to straighten that line selected vertices in this .blend file. How to get that line of vertices (edit: I mean the two end point vertices) to line up on an axis so I can then (edit: select the batch of vertices and then) scale them to 0 on that axis.

Comment: Okay, I can see why this is so tricky. It's that the vertices I wish to straighten are on an arbitrary angle in 3d space, so it appears to require setting up a "straightedge" to align the vertices to. Then put that edge exactly aligned to the two vertice end points. Then to get the vertices to align to the edge, some fancy things like select all the vertices, then select the edge last to make it active, then be sure to have pivot at active, and view at normal, then finally shift+y, and again shift+y, to get scaling to normal of the edge?, and finally press 0...and it works here.

Comment: Just thought there may be an easier way. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: If you need to add additional images, upload to imgur or some other image hosting site, paste in the links, and someone with more reputation will edit in the images.

Comment: @frew You will also have to '@' users if you want a user to get notified, e.g. '@RayMairlot'.

Comment: Sorry, new to the forum, not sure what it means to use @ to notify a user...do you mean in this comments section that in order to direct a comment to a specific user to start the comment with @ in front of their name?

Comment: @frew Yes. Like I did at the beginning of the comment. I'm only seeing your additional comments because I happen to check back on this post, otherwise I wouldn't notice it/get notified of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way would be to scale them along the y axis with your pivot set to "median point".

Select the vertices like you've shown in the picture then press <kbd>S</kbd> and then <kbd>Y</kbd>. Scale the vertices in and they will perfectly align. You may need to repeat these steps once or twice. Make sure proportional editing is turned off during this process.

Good luck.

Comment: Could not get that to work here, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: For reference I include this technique in this video by Gleb Alexandrov which shows another way to align vertices into a straight line, ie to straighten an edge line: https://youtu.be/3YteVJAvoYY?t=65

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align vertices into a straight line, select the ones of interest and scale them on the desired axis. Type in <kbd>0</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will set them all to the same median point on the axis, making a straight line.