# Tool similar to looping tool in 3d max

Tags: selection-tools, geometry

[image]is there a tool in blender that works similiar to how the looping tool in 3ds max works in which it will calculate my loop to auto clean my geometry. or make a curve i've been using loop tool addon however it it doesn't clean existing geometry just curves. It would be helpful if the tool also does like in max moves the edges to the center between the two existing edges. the tool that i'm looking for is set flow. if there are other tools like this in blender or a good addon to add similiar functions that would be helpful i dont want to spend hrs cleaning geometry if it can be sped up.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaqck.png)

so if the geometry is screwy like this
i need to clikc the loop flow a few times to get this
thats what i am looking for

[image]

Comment: Could you show the tool you are looking for in action? It is hard to understand what you are trying to replicate

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/how-do-i-space-quads-evenly/64595#64595

Comment: is there a cleaner versions that works closer to the loop tool in 3ds max