# How does one make vertices in line with the rest of the object's mesh?

Tags: mesh

Hello Blender community!

I'm working on a personal project in which I'm modelling a car.

[image: The car so far.]

Its mesh once had bezels, but I've decided to scrap them for now in order to lower the complexity of my mesh. In turn, this has caused the mesh to become a bit messy:

[image: The messy mesh.]

My goal is to make the top of the vehicle an even surface while still retaining its angle, and my loop cuts as straight as can be. I've highlighted my objectives in red.

[image: The uneven surface.]

[image: The crooked loop cut.]

In this situation I figured it would be incredibly useful to have vertex snapping while performing a vertex slide, but after doing some research I've found that this just isn't possible yet.

How should I go about cleaning this mesh up?

Also, how acceptable is it to have tris in my mesh? One of the reasons I got rid of the bezels was because they were creating tris and n-gons in my mesh. I aim to use **only** quads for the sake of managing loop cuts, and I frequently check this using the "Select faces by sides" feature.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64592/how-do-i-space-quads-evenly/64595#64595 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/is-there-a-way-to-align-multiple-vertices-to-another-vertex https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33525/straighten-vertices-along-a-line/38800#38800

Comment: If you want an edge loop to align with the next edge loop, press GG to slide, then E ,or E then F to align with the opposite side.